# Unique field name for arrays in Razor

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Model

```
public class DataModel
{
    public List<GeneratorReportModel> myGenerators{ get; set; }
}
```

and the View is

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "DataEntry", FormMethod.Post))
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
   {
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.myGenerators.ElementAt(i).my_field)
   <br />
   }
}
```

and the Controller to capture the form POST

```
public ActionResult Index(DataModel dataModel)
{
  return Content("ADDED>MYfieild>" dataModel.myGenerators.ElementAt(0).my_field);
}
```

When HTML is generated for above View all the textbox have the same "name" attribute and the value got at ActionResult on form post is always incorrect.
How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

Needs more info, try this pesudocode:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "DataEntry", FormMethod.Post))
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
   {
   <input type="text" name="my_field@i" value="@Model.myGenerators.ElementAt(i).my_field">
   <br />
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this generates unique name for each textbox but when i submit it still prints "ADDED>MYfieild>0" despite me entering another value in first textbox.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, if you instead use the indexer on the list, the ModelBinder will pick these up and name them correctly:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "DataEntry", FormMethod.Post))
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
   {
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.myGenerators[i].my_field)
   <br />
   }
}
```

This way the output will look more like:

```
<input type='textbox' name='myGenerators[0].my_field'/>
<input type='textbox' name='myGenerators[1].my_field'/>
```

The ModelBinder that is used on your controller is then able to interpret this as an `IEnumerable<T>` and you will see that you collection is initialised.